# When parsing an element of a html document, the conversion is missing a proceeding 0

Tags: c#, innerhtml

When I select an element of the html document, then convert it to an int64, its missing a preceding 0.

Using `InnerHtml`, I only want the last 4 characters from the "Prime Z790 BIOS 0812" result.

The result of this newz790 var should be 0812, but I just get 812.

```
namespace getsqldata
{
    public static class ASUSBIOSversions
    {
        public static long newz790;
        public static async Task Run()
            
        {

            //*****************Get BIOS info from website**************
            //Scrape Website
            {
                await GethtmlAsync();
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }
            async static Task GethtmlAsync()
            {

                //Get Url for scraping and create document for parsing
                var url = "https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-z790-p/helpdesk_bios/?model2Name=PRIME-Z790-P";


                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

                var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

                await Task.Delay(5000); // Add a delay of 5 seconds

                //Specify element of page to be retrieved
                var biositem = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'ProductSupportDriverBIOS__fileTitle')]");
                

                //Grab the BIOS version              
                ASUSBIOSversions.newz790 = Convert.ToInt64(biositem[0].InnerHtml[^4..]);
```

Comment: An `Int64` is an integer. No formatting concerns. It's only capable of storing `812`. If you want a *formatted number* with leading zeros, don't *convert what you have to an integer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int64 is an integer, and does not contain leading `0`'s. You can add leading zeros when casting it to a string, if you want to...

[In64 Reference and using leading Zeros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64?view=net-8.0#representing-an-int64-as-a-string)

If you need the zero, and grabbing it from a "string" in `innerHtml`, why not keep it a string?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're missing the preceding zero in the result is because you're converting the string to an Int64 (long) type. The Int64 type does not have leading zeroes, so the zero at the beginning of the string is simply ignored.

To preserve the leading zero, you should convert the string to a string type instead of an Int64 type. you need to change the type of newz790 to string.
If you need to check is it integer or not you jus tryparse and check.